# HTML/CSS Dropdown menu width. Help, please

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML/CSS dropdown menu on my site. I am having a bit of trouble with the width of the actual drop down and I cannot figure out what could be causing it. You can see that the dropdown width is the same as the nav bar width. The problem is some of the dropdown links are wider than the nav bar boxes, causing the words that exceed that width to drop down to the next line.

I hope that made some sort of sense. Here is the URL, HTML and CSS:

http://greatorlandodiscounts.com/test-june2014/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<!--Wrapper container start-->
<div id="wrapperContainer">
  <div id="topBar">
    <div id="wrapper"> 
      <!--top left phone number and icon start-->
      <div id="leftTop">
        <div id="facebookTop"> <a href="#"> <img src="images/facebook-icon.png" alt="GreatOrlandoDiscounts Become our friend on Facebook!" /> </a> </div>
        <p class="topLeftNumber">Call us at:
          <mark class="orange">1-800-544-7646</mark>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--top left phone number and icon end--> 
      <!--top right phone number and icon start-->
      <div id="rightTop">
        <div id="twitterTop"> <img src="images/twitter-icon.png" alt="GreatOrlandoDiscounts Follow us on Twitter" /> </div>
        <p class="topRightNumber">Call us at:
          <mark class="orange">1-800-544-7646</mark>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--top left phone number and icon end--> 
      <!--Left nav bar start-->
      <div id="leftNavBar"> 
        <!--left nav dropdown start-->
        <div id="navBarLeft">
          <div id="dropdownContainerLeft">
            <div id="menuLeft">
              <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="http://www.greatorlandodiscounts.com">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="attractions"><a href="#">THEME PARKS</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Disney Tickets</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Universal Orlando Resort</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Universal Studios Orlando</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Islands of Adventure</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">SeaWorld</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Legoland Florida</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Discovery Cove</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Disney Quest</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="attractions"><a href="#">WATER PARKS</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Disney</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Universal Studios</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">SeaWorld</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--left nav dropdown end--> 
      </div>
      <!--Left nav bar end--> 
      <!--Right nav bar start-->
      <div id="rightNavBar"> 
        <!--Right nav dropdown start-->
        <div id="navBarRight">
          <div id="dropdownContainerRight">
            <div id="menuRight">
              <ul>
                <li class="attractions"><a href="#">DINNER SHOWS</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Disney</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Universal Studios</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">SeaWorld</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="attractions"><a href="#">ATTRACTIONS</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Disney</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Universal Studios</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">SeaWorld</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="attractions"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Disney</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Universal Studios</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">SeaWorld</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                    <li class="attractions"><a href="#">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Right nav dropdown end--> 
      </div>
      <!--Right nav bar end--> 
      <!--Main image start - ONLY CHANGE IMAGE IN INLINE CODE-->
      <div id="mainImage"> <img src="images/main-image.jpg"  alt="Discount Walt Disney World Tickets" /> </div>
      <!--Main image end--> 
      <!--Logo start-->
      <div id="logo"> <a href="http://www.greatorlandodiscounts.com"> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Great Orlando Discount Tickets" /> </a> </div>
      <!--Logo end--> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Wrapper container end--> 

<!--Middle section start-->
<div id="midSecWrapper"> 
  <!--midSpacer start-->
  <div id="midSpacer"></div>
  <!--midSpacer end--> 
  <!--Content start-->
  <div id="midContent"> 
    <!--top section start-->
    <div id="topContent"> 
      <!--left ad box start-->
      <div id="leftAdBox"> <a href="#"> <img src="images/dis-front-ad.jpg" alt="Discount Disney World Tickets" /> </a> </div>
      <!--left ad box end--> 
      <!--center ad box start-->
      <div id="centerAdBox"> <a href="#"> <img class="centered" src="images/uni-front-ad.jpg" alt="Discount Universal Studios Orlando Tickets" /> </a> </div>
      <!--center ad box end--> 
      <!--right ad box start-->
      <div id="rightAdBox"> <a href="#"> <img class="topFrontRight" src="images/sea-front-ad.jpg" alt="Discount Sea World Orlando Tickets" /> </a> </div>
      <!--right ad box end--> 
    </div>
    <!--top section end--> 

    <!--center section start-->
    <div id="centerContent"> 
      <!--center left begin-->
      <div id="centerLeft">
        <h2> Special Disney Ticket Offer! </h2>
        <p class="specCont"> <img class="specImg" src="images/dis-tick-front.jpg" alt="Special Disney Ticket Offer!" /> Super Value Disney 3 Day Touch of Magic Ticket! Just $219 for each ticket! Get 3 Days to visit the Disney Theme Parks (Magic Kingdom,        Epcot, Hollywood Studios, Animal Kingdom) PLUS a 4th day at Disney Quest, Blizzard Beach or Typhoon Lagoon! For an unbelievable value!        Call &amp; ask for the Resort offer<br />
          (restrictions apply).<br />
          <strong>Call us: 1-800-544-7646</strong> </p>
      </div>
      <!--center left end--> 
      <!--center right begin-->
      <div id="centerRight"> <a href="#"> <img class="rightFrontImg" src="images/legoland-fl-front-ad.jpg" alt="Legoland Florida Discount Tickets" /> </a> </div>
      <!--center right end--> 
    </div>
    <!--center section end--> 

    <!--under center content start-->
    <div id="underCenter"> 
      <!--under center left start-->
      <div id="unCenLeft"> <a href="#"> <img class="leftFrontImg" src="images/3musk-front.jpg" alt="The 3 Musketeers Dinner Show Discount Tickets" /> </a> </div>
      <!--under center left end--> 
      <!--under center right start-->
      <div id="unCenRight"> <a href="#"> <img class="rightFrontImg" src="images/wild-fl-front.jpg" alt="The 3 Musketeers Dinner Show Discount Tickets" /> </a> </div>
      <!--under center right start--> 
    </div>
    <!--under center content end--> 

    <!--main content start-->
    <div id="mainContentContainer"> 
      <!--main left start-->
      <div id="mainLeft"> <img class="mainContImg" src="images/disney-char.jpg" alt="Walt Disney World Discount Tickets" /> </div>
      <!--main left end--> 
      <!--main right start-->
      <div id="mainRight">
        <h3> Discount Disney World Tickets </h3>
        <p class="contOrange"> To help us keep great Disney ticket prices, please click the +1 on the left or follow us on Facebook for great deals and discounts and     prizes.<br />
          FREE Standard USPS delivery in the US and FREE office pick up. *Office open from Mon-Sat 8am-8pm, Sun 8am-5pm. Closed on Christmas. </p>
        <p class="mainInfoPara"> OK - Let's cut right to business. You came here surfing for discount Disney World tickets and that's what we offer. We are an authorized, full-service, official Disney ticket provider, Universal Studios ticket supplier and SeaWorld ticket seller. We are also authorized OFFICIAL ticket resellers for Busch Gardens tickets, all Orlando dinner show tickets and Orlando Florida theme park attraction ticket resellers. The name Billy Boy's Tickets is known worldwide as a legitimate leader in discount attraction tickets. Licensed, bonded, certified Florida sellers of travel - we have our IATA & CLIA travel agent certifications and stand behind EVERY ticket we sell. We are a one stop shop for Disney tickets, hotel accommodations, rental cars, home rentals and more. DON'T chase around the web, dealing with fly by night websites that may or may not have valid tickets. Go with a name you can trust - Billy Boy's Discount Disney Tickets. </p>
      </div>
      <!--main right end--> 
    </div>
    <!--main content end--> 

    <!--youtube container start-->
    <div id="youTubeContainer"> 
      <!--youtube container left start-->
      <div id="youTubeLeft">
        <h4> Why Should You Buy From Us? </h4>
        <p class="youtubeCont"> There are good reasons to buy your discount Disney tickets and Orlando theme park tickets from us vs. other discount Disney ticket wholesalers or internet sites that are out there. Let us help you with your affordable Disney vacations. </p>
        <ul class="whyBuyList">
          <li>Over 31 years in the same location</li>
          <li>We are open 7 days a week</li>
          <li>Licensed discount wholesaler</li>
          <li>We use Secure Sockey Layer Technology</li>
          <li>Disney Group Discounts</li>
          <li>Never purchase Used Disney Tickets</li>
          <li>EVERY ticket we sell is NEW</li>
          <li>THE trusted name in discount Disney tickets</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="youtubeCont"> As you can see, GreatOrlandoDiscounts can get you the best deals on discount Orlando tickets the fast, safe and easy way. Let us help you get the tickets that you need for your visit. </p>
      </div>
      <!--youtube container left end--> 
      <!--youtube container right start-->
      <div id="youTubeRight">
        <h4>Epcot Food and Wine Festival</h4>
        <p class="youTube">
          <iframe width="440" height="248" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FV0jEBb2W24" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--youtube container right end--> 
    </div>
    <!--youtube container end--> 

  </div>
  <!--Content end--> 
</div>
<!--Middle section end--> 

<!--spacer start-->
<div id="preFootSpacer"> </div>
<!--spacer end--> 

<!--footer start--> 
<!--footer background container start-->
<div id="footerBg"> 
  <!--footer content start-->
  <div id="footerContent"> 
    <!--footer left start-->
    <div id="footerLeft">
      <p class="footContLeft"> &copy; 2014-15 ~ Rocker Fruit Company. All Rights Reserved. </p>
    </div>
    <!--footer left end--> 
    <!--footer right start-->
    <div id="footerRight">
      <p class="footContRight"> <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Term &amp; Conditions</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Shipping &amp; Devlivery</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">About Us</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Contact Us</a> </p>
    </div>
    <!--footer right end--> 
  </div>
  <!--footer content end--> 
</div>
<!--footer background container end--> 
<!--footer end-->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url(../images/body-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

#wrapperContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:501px;
}

#topBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    background-image:url(../images/top-bar.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    height: 501px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
    width: 260px;
    height: 185px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#leftTop {
    width: 350px;
    height: 58px;
    float: left;
}

#rightTop {
    width: 360px;
    height: 58px;
    float: right;
}

#mainImage {
    width: 980px;
    height: 401px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
    margin-top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: -2px;
    display:block;
}

#facebookTop {
    float:left;
    margin: 4px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#twitterTop {
    float:right;
    margin: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#leftNavBar {
    width: 340px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    z-index:600;
}

#rightNavBar {
    width: 360px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    z-index:700;
}

#midSecWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

#midSpacer {
    width: 980px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image:url(../images/spacer.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    clear: both;
}

#midContent {
    width:980px;
    height:125px;
    clear:both;
}

#topContent {
    width: 980px;
    height: 125px;
}

#leftAdBox {
    width:324px;
    height:125px;
    float:left;
}

#centerAdBox {
    width:334px;
    height:125px;
    float:left;
}

#rightAdBox {
    width:322px;
    height:125px;
    float:right;
}

#centerContent {
    width: 980px;
    height: 238px;
}

#centerLeft {
    width: 572px;
    height: 238px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../images/center-left-bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#centerRight {
    width: 408px;
    height: 238px;
    float:right;
}

#underCenter {
    width:980px;
    height:121px;
}

#unCenLeft {
    width:487px;
    height:121px;
    float:left;
}

#unCenRight {
    width:493px;
    height:121px;
    float:right;
}

#mainContentContainer {
    width:980px;
    height:418px;
    background-image:url(../images/main-cont.png);
}

#mainLeft {
    width:511px;
    height:418px;
    float: left;
}

#mainRight {
    width:469px;
    height:418px;
    float: right;
}

#youTubeContainer {
    width:980px;
    height:366px;
}

#youTubeLeft {
    width:489px;
    height:366px;
    background-image:url(../images/youtubeLeft.png);
    float: left;
}

#youTubeRight {
    width:491px;
    height:366px;
    background-image:url(../images/youtubeRight.png);
    float: right;
}

#preFootSpacer {
    width: 980px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear:both;
    background-image:url(../images/spacer.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#footerBg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 57px; 
    background-image:url(../images/footer-bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    clear:both;
}

#footerContent {
    width: 980px;
    height: 57px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footerLeft {
    width: 386px;
    height: 57px;
    float: left;
}

#footerRight {
    width: 594px;
    height: 57px;
    float: right;
}

h2 {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #c74426;
}

h3 {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 5px;
    color: #c74426;
}

h4 {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 25px;
    color: #c74426;
}

.mainInfoPara {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 0px 5px;
    color: #454f54;
}

.contOrange {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 15px 0px 5px;
    color: #c74426;
}

.mainContImg {
    padding-top: 9px;
}

.specCont {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
    color: #454f54;
}

.specImg {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.leftFrontImg {
    margin-top:10px;
    float: left;
}

.rightFrontImg {
    margin-top:10px;
    float: right;
}

.centered {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

.topFrontRight {
    float:right;
}

.topLeftNumber {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #e1ebf4;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.topRightNumber {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #e1ebf4;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align:right;
}

mark.orange {
    color:#fa7252;
    background: none;
}

.youTube {
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 31px;
}

.youtubeCont {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 15px 0px 25px;
    color: #c74426;
}

.twitterTop {
}

.whyBuyList {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 10px 15px 0px 25px;
    color: #454f54;
}

.footContLeft {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 24px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.footContRight {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 24px 0px 0px 55px;
}

.footContRight a {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
} 

.footContRight a:hover {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #c74426;
} 

/*Nav bar style left*/
#menuLeft {
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
}
#menuLeft ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menuLeft li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#menuLeft li a{
    font-size: 12px;
    width:110px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #9d9d9d;
    color: #454f54;
}

#menuLeft li a:hover{ 
    background-image: url(../images/nav-hover-bg.jpg); 
    color: #fa7252; 
    background-color: #e1ebf4;
}

#menuLeft ul ul{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #e1ebf4; 
    color: #22293c;
}

#menuLeft ul li:hover ul{ 
    visibility:visible; 
    color: #22293c; 
}
/*Nav Bar Style left end*/

/*Nav bar style right*/
#menuRight {
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
}
#menuRight ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menuRight li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#menuRight li a{
    font-size: 12px;
    width:120px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #9d9d9d;
    color: #454f54;
}

#menuRight li a:hover{ 
    background-image: url(../images/nav-hover-bg.jpg); 
    color: #fa7252; background-color: #e1ebf4;
}

#menuRight ul ul{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    background-color: #e1ebf4; 
    color: #22293c;
}

#menuRight ul li:hover ul{ 
    visibility:visible; 
    color: #22293c; 
}
/*Nav Bar Style right end*/
```

Thank you in advance for any and all help, advice and/or suggestions. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the question/ what is the desired output..?

Comment: I'm getting a DNS error trying to hit your link above. Did your demo go down?

Comment: @T J Thank you very much for your fast response! If you look at the dropdown menu and you scroll over, say Theme Parks, and you go down to the third entry/link that says Universal Studios, it is supposed to say Universal Studios Orlando. It actually is there, but the Orlando part drops down to the next line instead of the entire Universal Studios Orlando being on one line. I cannot seem to get the drop down portion on the menu to be as wide as the words. I hope that made sense.

Comment: @ajm Thanks for your response. Sorry, I fixed the OP. Here is the link: http://greatorlandodiscounts.com/test-june2014/

Comment: please give us a code which is having problem? its a very big code.

Comment: @Hamza Thank you for your response. The code I believe I am having trouble with is in the CSS. It starts at /*Nav bar style left*/ in the style sheet. The HTML starts at <!--Left nav bar start-->.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by a couple of your selectors "cascading" down to items in your flyout menus.

`#menuLeft li a` sets a width of 110px on anchor tags in the top navigation. It also has the side effect of selecting your anchor tags in your flyout menus, capping their widths at 110px and forcing their text to wrap. `#menuLeft li` floats list-items to the left, which causes them to "snap" to the 110px width of your top-level navigation anchor tags, which makes your flyouts narrow.

You can override that styling with something like this:

```
#menuLeft li ul a {
    white-space: nowrap;  /* Force links not to wrap at all */
    width: auto;          /* Allow them to take up as much width as they need */
}
```

That will force your links to take up a single line, but since your list-items are floated, you will need a bit of visual space between the link text and your flyout's background color (IMHO, anyway :-)).

This will give you a bit of space:

```
#menuLeft li ul li {
    float: none;    /* No need to float these links at all. */
    padding: 0 .5em;  /* Bit of space. YMMV. */
}
```

Comment: Also, check the spelling of "Secure Sockets Layer" in your "Why should you buy from us?" bullets.

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. Thank you very much for your time and help. Here is a virtual beer for you on me! I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what you accomplished in 30 minutes. I truly appreciate it. How do you select best answer or give your rep points?

Comment: There should be a green check somewhere by the upvote/downvote arrows to mark the answer. Virtual beers are almost as good as the real thing!

Comment: Perfect! I checked the green arrow by your solution. Again, I really appreciate you taking the time to help my out with this. Thanks!